# TableView data's are disappear while scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried so many examples But doesn't works.Please check my code and give solutions.Thanks in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
if (indexPath.section==0)
{
    img=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    img.frame=CGRectMake(25, 15, 75, 75);
    img.layer.cornerRadius=6.0;
    img.clipsToBounds=YES;
    img.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];


    [img addTarget:self action:@selector(takePic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    img.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    text=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 30, 200, 30)];
    text.placeholder=@"Name";
    [text setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [cell addSubview:text];
    [cell addSubview:img];
    else if (indexPath.section==1)
{
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 15, 100, 20)];
    label.text=[dosageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [cell addSubview:label];
  return cell;
     }}
```

I have a three section in the tableview.In first Section I have a textfield and imageview If I scroll the textfield and imageview will disappear that is the problem

Comment: explain in deep ...i cant get it clearly , wt is use of else condition >
?

Comment: What is the use of this `if (cell == nil)` whether this is true or false you are doing the same thing. Also you are just creating a cell and returning it. Where are you assigning data ?

Comment: @iPatel Thanks..I have a three section in the tableview.In first Section I have a textfield and imageview If I scroll the textfield and imageview will disappear that is the problem

Comment: cany you post your textfield and imageview added code in this block.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code add NSMutableArray to all.Here displayArray is NSMutableArray.

```
text.text=[displayArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note :** if you have limited data then use **SOLUTION - 1** because this is bad for memory management , Other wise **SOLUTION - 2** is good for you. (*Solution - 1 may be helpful for u*)

**SOLUTION - 1**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {   
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"NameOFData "; 

   return cell;
}
```

## SOLUTION - 2

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)  
   {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"NameOFData "; 

   return cell;
}
```

**EDITED :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {   
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (indexPath.section==0)
           {
    img=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    img.frame=CGRectMake(25, 15, 75, 75);
    img.layer.cornerRadius=6.0;
    img.clipsToBounds=YES;
    img.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];


    [img addTarget:self action:@selector(takePic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    img.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    text=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 30, 200, 30)];
    text.placeholder=@"Name";
    [text setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [cell addSubview:text];
    [cell addSubview:img];
      }
        }

            cell.textLabel.text = @"NameOFData "; 

       return cell;
    }
```

Comment: put your whole component (imgaeView,textfield,....etch) in between ...if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }...

Answer (score 0):

remove `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`  from else part & leave it blank

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: ok then try with this UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

return cell;

Comment: @ForamMukundShah That won't be a issue. Because he is always creating a new cell

Comment: No, it will be an issue because he is creating new cell, even if cell is not equal to nil

Comment: ohhh!! I just took a look at your code & found you have written return cell inside the braces

Comment: write return cell after curly brace other wise, table will not return any cell

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
 
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = @""// value from your datasource
    
    return cell;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

          static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          if (cell == nil)
          {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

          }
           return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION 1**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//your code

}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text= @"YOUR TEXT";

}
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!